# What is the meaning of the term FQBN?

Tags: terminology

So I'm reading the [Platform specification](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/platform-specification/#custom-board-options) and doing some programming and I'm getting the error:

```
Error missing FQBN
```

So what does FQBN mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: Fully Qualified Board Name

I.e., a descriptor that uniquely identifies a board and its configuration.

Comment: That sounds about right. Just couldn't think of the right words for these letters and the net is quite silent about the meaning of it. But thanks and I'll be accepting when the site lets me

Comment: I guess it's a modification of "FQDN" - Fully Qualified Domain Name used in networking. If you know FQDN that only leaves the B to interpret, and there's not many things it can be in relation to Arduinos...

Comment: @TarickWelling, Arduino started to use this acronym recently with the new Arduino CLI.